# When sort a column in antd Table component the color for sorting override my css

Tags: css, reactjs, sorting, antd

i sort a column in antd Table component and the entire column takes a default color. The problem is that i have custom `css` applied on my `rows` but when i sort them the default color of antd for sort override my custom css. I am writting `reactjs`

```
  <Table
    size='small'
    dataSource={this.state.codes}
    rowClassName={(record, index) => ((record.package_name===null ? 'disable' : ''))}
    columns={[  }]
```

My own css that applied to all the row is on the `rowClassName`
What i want is to when i sort a column the default sort css not to be applied and override my custom css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, the `css selector` that is responsible for sort in antd is this `td.ant-table-column-sort`. So inside my `CSS` file i have insert this code:

```
.even > td.ant-table-column-sort {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Where `even` is my custom `CSS`

Comment: **The_elevator** thanks! I was facing the same issue, and I was able to resolve it because of your answer. Apart from the rows, the background color of my Table Column Header was also changed due to sorting. After some investigation, I applied the following CSS code to customize the Column Header style -


`.my-ant-design-table .ant-table-thead > tr > th {
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
}`

Where `.my-ant-design-table` is the class name given to the Ant Table, like below -

`<Table
    className='my-ant-design-table'
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={rows}
>`